# how to consume rest api of apache nutch docker

Tags: apache, docker, nutch

I pulled and started [apache nutch docker](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchRESTAPI)
started it with

```
docker run --name my_nutch -d -p 8899:8899 -e SOLRURL=192.168.99.100:8983 -t meabed/nutch
```

any action I try to consume ([according to their rest api](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchRESTAPI)) - I get 404
for example

```
192.168.99.100:8899/admin
```

tried also

GET  http://192.168.99.100:8899/nutch/#/admin

I get in postman (for all GET REST requests, POST I get 404)

```
[
  [
    "admin",
    "Service admin actions"
  ],
  [
    "confs",
    "Configuration manager"
  ],
  [
    "db",
    "DB data streaming"
  ],
  [
    "jobs",
    "Job manager"
  ]
]
```