# docker of solr and nutch working together?

Tags: solr, docker, web-crawler, nutch, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to activate nutch and solr as dockers out of the box to consume that in REST.
Tried

1. [same docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/momer/docker-solr-nutch/) - started it with

   ```
   docker run --name nutch_solr -d -p 8899:8899 -p 8983:8983 -t momer/docker-solr-nutch:4.6.1
   ```

can't surf to ..:8983, or ...:8899

2. Tried different dockers - [nutch](https://hub.docker.com/r/meabed/nutch/) and [solr](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/)
   started it with:

   ```
   docker run --name my_nutch -d -p 8899:8899 -e SOLRURL=192.168.99.100:8983 -t meabed/nutch
   ```

Solr is up and running, but can't really work with nutch ([my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218424/how-to-consume-rest-api-of-apache-nutch-docker))

tried more another nutch docker - what am I missing? I'd like to write a post on how to raise solr and nutch dockers in 5 minutes, but I just can't seem to work with it..

so, does someone know how to activate it including send a sample of crawling job for work?

Comment: Are you using the docker-machine ip <yourmachine> in order to surf to 8983?

Comment: of course :) btw - I'm using docker toolbox for windows - it's coming with 192.168.99.100 IP. BTW - I'm looking in solving the issue of how to communicate with nutch first. solr integration may come in later stage... not sure how to interact with nutch with postman

Comment: Is it working from localhost (meaning from within the docker machine)? Ie, maybe that service is configure to listen to 127.0.0.1 only instead of broadcast 0.0.0.0.

Comment: How did you get solr + nutch in the same container?  I see the apache/solr and apache/nutch containers on docker hub, but near as I can tell the solr official solr container doesn't have nutch in it.